# How to make an association between a keyboard and a particular window icon?

Tags: keyboard, icons, windows-xp

I want to create associations between a key and an icon on Windows.

For example, every time I push <kbd>F1</kbd> I want to have the effect of having a desk free of windows, I want them all to be minimized.

OS: Windows XP SP 3

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: From his previous questions, I assumed Windows.

Comment: @EricR: I´m using windows xp service pack 3

Answer (score 2):

So It looks like you are trying to make your own hot keys for your own, or already existing, computer functions(I.E. Run Internet Explorer When F1, Open CD Tray If F12). You could make software to do that for you, (take input and then do something depending on input) but It seems like you want to run this off your desktop at any time, But you failed to mention what OS you are running?

There is an infinite number of questions or answers that could spawn off something so vague like this. Let us know what your using as an OS and what you've tried already.

Answer (score 1):

By icon you mean an executable file I assume? Check out this great article on mapping keyboard keys to executable files [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17654/create-keyboard-shortcuts-to-applications-in-windows/). For minimizing all the windows, you could create an executable script, save it somewhere, and use the program to map a keyboard shortcut for it (although `Windows + D` already does this. One thing to note is that [Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-vista/Create-keyboard-shortcuts-to-open-programs) only allows shortcuts of the kind `Ctrl + Alt + Key.` So you won't be able to use F1 as a hotkey.